How does Admit into unstructured Phd in Psychology in Germany work?
I have a specific interest in studying about alexithymia. I have also drafted a research proposal and emailed it to professors from various universities across Germany. But I haven't received any reply even after 4 months of writing to them. I would like to know if I am falling short somewhere and if there is a way to improve on the PhD pitch. Is there anybody who can share your experience in applying for an unstructured PhD position in Germany?

To add some context to my answer: I am a Phd student in Germany, albeit in a computer science (CS) related field. I studied at a different university before my Phd, and got my position by cold-e-mailing group leads, whose work I found interesting. By cold-e-mailing, I mean that in most cases, there was no open position being advertised. Whenever possible, I included personal references, e.g. having met the recipient at a conference, or being referred to that person's work by my thesis advisor. I tried to keep it short to save their time, and included references of where my prior work meshed with their research. I had some publications at workshops and local conferences at that time, which made it possible for them to check my claims, although showing knowledge about a topic in your e-mail may also be possible. Through this process, I received one referral to an open position with a different professor, which ultimately didn't quite fit my interests, and two invitations to an interview, one of which led to my current position. Some people did not react to my e-mail. I have tried to extract some of what helped me in the following.
First, in my experience, professors supervise Phd students in their own area of interest, and also based on the projects they have funding for. So, the professors you have e-mailed may either not be interested in alexithymia, or may have a grant to work on different topics, even if they are interested in it. So, your focus on a very concrete topic may be hindering your application.
Additionally, many of the Phd students I know had a prior connection to their current advisor, either studying at the same university, or studying with a colleague of the professor, or otherwise receiving a recommendation from someone the professor trusts. Professors receive many e-mails with requests, so yours might be getting lost in the heap, and they don't know anything about you besides your e-mail. Having a recommendation from someone they know can provide a signal that it is worthwhile for them to further spend time with your application, e.g. by asking their contact about you. That recommendation can be from a co-author, former student who is now a professor elsewhere, or someone from the same field, who attends/publishes at the same conferences as the professor you are interested in working with. This last recommendation is probably mostly relevant from a CS-perspective, as most of our publications are conference publications, so you get to know people from there, and a recommendation from someone I talked with at a conference would be a signal of trust to me. I would talk to some of your own professors to see if they can refer you to some of their German colleagues.
Finally, you also mentioned writing to "professors from various universities across Germany". How well are your e-mails tailored to the professor? Like I wrote above, professors get lots of e-mail, and you need to show that you want to work with this person specifically, that you have read their research and that your research proposal or research interests fit into their profile. An unstructured Phd in Germany is to some degree a personal (work) relationship between you and your advisor, so it needs to fit. Some professors also post requests on their websites that you include some specific phrase or word in your e-mails or the subject line to show that you have taken the time to research them. Ensure that you do that.
tldr; Tailor your e-mail to your recipient and their research interests. Get a referral from someone your recipient may know or trust, if possible. And be prepared to work on a topic that is different from what you have proposed.
